Why Does Flow Direction and Language remains unchanged in the current page?
I implemented a way to set the culture in a .NET MAUI application like this :
LoginPage.xaml
<Picker x:Name="LanguagePicker"
        Title="Select Language"
        SelectedIndexChanged="OnLanguageChanged">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>English</x:String>
        <x:String>Arabic</x:String>
        <x:String>French</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>

LoginPage.xaml.cs
private void OnLanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var picker = sender as Picker;
    var selectedLanguage = picker.SelectedItem.ToString();

    CultureInfo culture = selectedLanguage switch
    {
        "Arabic" => new CultureInfo("ar"),
        "French" => new CultureInfo("fr"),
        _ => new CultureInfo("en"),
    };



    LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(culture);

    // Refresh UI
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppResources));
}

LocalizationResourceManager.cs
 public class LocalizationResourceManager:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public static LocalizationResourceManager Instance { get; } = new();
     public object this[string resourceKey]=>AppResources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey, AppResources.Culture)?? Array.Empty<byte>();
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     public LocalizationResourceManager()
     {
         AppResources.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
     }

     public void SetCulture(CultureInfo culture)
     {


         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

         CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
         CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
         CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
         AppResources.Culture = culture;
 
         
     }
     protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }

AppResources.Designer.cs
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "17.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
internal class AppResources {
    
    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
    
    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
    
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal AppResources() {
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Strada.Resources.Strings.AppResources", typeof(AppResources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
    ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Account.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string Account {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Account", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
    }


Issues with the above code

the  language is not set in the current page it is set after pushing the next page (after Shell.Current.GoTo...)
the Flow direction remains the same even if the language is Arabic

can you provide me a solution
I was expecting the language and flow direction to change in the same page and future pushed pages.

May I know what platform you are targeting, also the .NET version you're using?

I'm using Android , .net 8

Thanks for your response, can I know how do you define AppResources, can you help add that in your post?

I defined it in visual studio by adding new "Resources File" in visual studio named AppReources.resx and it automatically generates AppReources.Designer.cs when adding key value pairs for associated string and it contains by default Culture info I'll provide it in the above code


In your LoginPage.xaml.cs, try to add public LocalizationResourceManager LocalizationResourceManager { get; }  and then add LocalizationResourceManager = LocalizationResourceManager.Instance; in the constructor.  2. On Android, if you want to enable right-to-left locales, you need to set the android:supportsRtl  attribute on the  node in the app's AndroidManifest.xml file, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/localization?view=net-maui-8.0#android-2


the issue of changing language is fixed thanks!! but the one concerning Flow direction is still LTR although the language becomes arabic (RTL)

My pleasure! I can reproduce the issue, when switching the language from English to Arabic, it's still LTR which would have been RTL. And this issue is related with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14755 , you try to can change the device language to Arabic(RTL) to fix it.
